# Is a retry necessary here in a timeout?

Tags: ruby, timeout, hashicorp-vault

I have the following code:

```
task :wait_for_vault_ssl_up do
  Timeout::timeout(15) do
    begin
      TCPSocket.new('localhost', 8200).close
      puts "Vault ssl up and ready!"
      true
    rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED, Errno::EHOSTUNREACH, SocketError
      puts "Vault ssl not ready... retrying"
      retry
      false
    end
  end
  rescue Timeout::Error
    false
end
```

In this, i set a timeout of 15 seconds and try to connect to the `localhost:8200` my question is, if its not up, i currently do a retry in the rescue. is that necessary or will it automatically continue trying to connect for 15 seconds?

Comment: `TCPSocket.new` has a `connect_timeout` option that will raise `Errno::ETIMEDOUT`. Don't use `Timeout::timeout` in a situation like this.

Comment: @Stefan how should i handle waiting for a port to be open? can you provide a solution? just retrying on the tcp connect for a given time?

Comment: Write a loop that keeps trying to connect. You probably want to [`sleep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Kernel.html#sleep-method) some time after a failed attempt.

Comment: BTW, `Timeout::timeout(15)` will _interrupt_ the given block after 15 seconds, no matter what. It's used to forcefully terminate long-running operations, like you would `kill -9` an unresponsive process. You usually don't want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `retry` will retry the execution of the whole block being rescued. So in this case, `retry` will start execution over again at your call to `TCPSocket.new`. This will happen *immediately* after the exception is rescued and there will not be a delay.

As Stefan has mentioned in the comments, you should use [`Kernel#sleep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Kernel.html#sleep-method) before calling `retry`. This will continue retrying until interrupted, so if you found yourself in a situation where the SSL connection will never be ready, the code will loop forever. You can either keep track of a retry count, or continue utilizing `Timeout::timeout`, using a longer timeout length, at which point the loop should give up entirely.

I think the clearer and simpler solution would be to use a retry counter, and give up after a predefined number of retries.